# Akka Persistence Maven coordinates for latest stable version?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, akka

I am brand new to Akka and am very confused about the Maven coordinates of its various modules.

**I would like to be on what is considered to be the latest *stable* version of Akka.** I don't need bleeding edge features. I'm brand new.

In my `build.gradle` file I added:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.3'
    compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.12'
}
```

This pulls in various binaries/dependencies and has allowed me to do simple things like creates `UntypedActor` subclasses, pass messages to them, etc.

I would like to now implement [Actor Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/persistence.html) with, say, Mongo DB as the backing store, however it doesn't appear that I have any `akka.persistence.*` classes on my runtime classpath. This leads me to believe that Akka Persistence is a full bore *module* that I need to pull in as a separate JAR.

So, despite the fact that I am using `akka-actor_2.10`, I added the following to my Gradle build:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.3'
    compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.12'
    compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-persistence_2.11:2.4-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

When I run this, no such `akka-persistence_2.11:2.4-SNAPSHOT` jar is pulled into my project. This leaves me with several questions:

- What dependency (specific Maven coordinates) do I need to include so that I'm on the latest stable "core Akka" (`akka-actor`) module?; and
- What dependency (specific Maven coordinates) do I need to include so that I'm on the latest stable Akka persistence module, thereby giving me the ability to implement message/actor persistence?
- What's the first version number in all Akka modules (`2.10` vs `2.11`, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out for Akka 2.3.* you need the [experimental persistence module](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/scala/persistence.html#Dependencies), which will become a stable/core feature of Akka in 2.4.

According to the Akka community, just because its marked as "*experimental*" doesn't mean that you're a mad scientist playing with fire and alchemy by using it in production, it just means that the module hasn't be around long enough for the community at large to officially mark it as stable.

At the time of this writing, the 2.3 version of Akka-Persistence has been around a little over a year and is considered to be very stable, even though its still marked as experimental. HTH.